# linq filtering by class type

Tags: c#, list, linq, filtering

I have a list contains 2 different types of objects which are polylines and texts.
I want to create a new list of polylines only.

what I do is;

```
var list2 = list1.SelectMany(x=> x.Type == PolyLine)
```

Error:'PolyLine' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

How do I filter those objects here?

Comment: Is `PolyLine` really the type of `x` or is `Type` some kind of enum? In the first case, simply use `var list2 = list1.OfType<PolyLine>().ToList();`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply use the [`OfType<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.7.2) extension:

```
var list2 = list1.OfType<PolyLine>().ToList();
```

This selects all elements in `list1` that are of type `PolyLine`.

After `ToList()` the resulting type of `list2` is `List<PolyLine>`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `SelectMany` rather you need a `Where` clause:

```
var result = list1.Where(x => x is PolyLine);
```

This uses the `is` operator to get the correct type.

This could further be simplified with the use of `OfType` extension method.